# How exactly do transformations affect constants?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-constants

So, I'm in high school and I've just been learning Quantum Mechanics. I'm trying to understand some concepts, since I'm interested in them, and I was having trouble resolving some doubts.

Namely, how exactly do constants undergo transformations? Say if I have the transformation;
$$
(\hbar, E)\longmapsto(\hbar+2\pi, E)
$$
What exactly does this mean? How is the constant undergoing transformation? I've seen this transformation in this paper:

- Y. Hatsuda, H. Katsura and Y. Tachikawa, "Hofstadter's butterfly in quantum geometry", [New J. Phys. **18** (2016) 103023](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/18/10/103023)

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/555381/258881

Comment: The transformation is changing the flux, not the constant.

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused since the rest of the paper seems to be using phi to represent flux, instead of the reduced planck's constant.